# Not able to import from `gensim.summarization` module in Django

Tags: python, django, nlp, gensim

I have included the 2 import statements in my views.py

```
from gensim.summarization.summarizer import summarizer
from gensim.summarization import keywords
```

However, even after I installed gensim using pip, I am getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.summarization'
```

Comment: You might have installed them globally or in some other virtual environment than the one you might be using for your Django project. OR it might be that you have a file or package of your own named `gensim`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, I activated my venv then I installed it. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I have also given another possibility in the above comment which seems more likely to me, which is that you have a file named `gensim.py` or a package named `gensim` in your _own_ code... (Notice that it says `No module named 'gensim.summarization'` and not `No module named 'gensim'`)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, yeah maybe. Can you help me on what should I do? Im afraid to delete any files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `summarization` code was removed from Gensim 4.0. See:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#12-removed-gensimsummarization

> ##### 12. Removed `gensim.summarization`
>
> Despite its general-sounding name, the module will not satisfy the
> majority of use cases in production and is likely to waste people's
> time. See [this Github
> ticket](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2592) for
> more motivation behind this.

If you need it, you could try:

- installing the older gensim version; or…
- copy the source code out to your own local module

However, I expect you'd likely be disappointed by its inflexibility and how little it can do.

It was *only* extractive summarization - choosing a few key sentences from those that already exist. That only gives impressive results when the source text was already well-written in an expository style mixing high-level overview sentences with separate detail sentences. And, its method of analyzing/ranking words was very crude & hard-to-customize – totally unconnected to the more generic/configurable/swappable approaches used elsewhere in Gensim or in other text libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `pip freeze` within your environment to ensure it is installed here.

If it is, then you should check naming of any modules or files you have in your directory to ensure there are no conflicts.

Comment: when I run pip freeze, I am getting the error pip._vendor.pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==21.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application ::((

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

As per Gensim’s Github changelog 188, `gensim.summarization` module has been removed in versions Gensim 4.x as it was an unmaintained third-party module.

To continue using `gensim.summarization`, you will need to downgrade the version of Gensim in the requirements.txt file by replacing it with `gensim==3.8.3` or an older version.